# Is there a way to create a unordered list with subitems from 1 content-type

Tags: list, html-lists, 2sxc, subitem

I would like to create a organogram like:
https://codepen.io/bernardoantunes/pen/inrbh using 2sic Content.

I would like to create a content-type 'organogram' with the following fields:
Title as String
Parent as Entity (of type Organogram)
Description as String
Link as Hyperlink

Using this content-type i would add some elements where child elements could be created.
for example:
- Root
- Child 1 (Root is selected in the Parent field)
- Child 2 (Root is selected in the Parent field)
- Child 3 (Child 2 is selected in the Parent field)

Could this be done using 2sic content App?

I created the content-type and added some elements. Created a razor template and then it gives an error.
operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type System.Collections.Generic.List  and ToSic.SexyContent.DynamicEntity

Razor template:

```
@using Connect.Koi;
@{
var first = AsDynamic(Data["Default"]).First();
var all = AsDynamic(Data["Default"]);
}
<div>@first.Title</div>  
var children = all.Where(x => x.parent == first).ToList();
<div>@children.Count</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the `AsDynamic(...)` creates wrapped entity-objects, whereas `...parent` gives you a list of related items (because it could have more than 1 parent). If this is the code you want to use, I suggest 1 things.

1. On the `.parent` (which should probably be .Parent) use the [0] or .FirstOrDefault() so it's `.Parent.FirstOrDefault() == first` - remember to enable LINQ by `@using System.Linq`
2. Don't compare the AsDynamic objects, because they will be different objects. Better compare the id using .EntityId or something.

So you're resulting compare will probably be `.Parent[0].EntityId == first.EntityId`.

What I don't like about your solution is the idea, that the first item in the Default-list will somehow be the important one. This doesn't feel right, but I don't know your whole solution...

Comment: fyi: we just released 2sxc 9.41, which has some great enhancements for better LINQ. I'll blog about it soon.